# Exim4 configuration expand the $message_headers variable to extract the message subject

Tags: exim

I have to send to an external program every subject of messages recevided from Exim server.

This is my **acl_smtp_data** config:

```
warn condition = ${lookup mysql{ INSERT INTO maillog ( subject ) VALUES ( '${quote_mysql:$message_headers}'}{$value}fail}
```

This works, but I would like to save only the "Subject" header and not all headers. I could not find a variable for only the subject, maybe I can extract it from all headers of the $message_headers var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either `$h_subject` or `$rh_subject` to access the header.  This is the standard way to access pretty well any header you want to access.  The `$rh_` variant is the raw undecoded header, while the `$h_` has been decoded.  There is also a `$bh` header which is part way between the two.  These are documented in the `String expansions` chapter of the [Exim specification](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/index.html).

I write the subject into a database using the column assignment

```
subject = '${rxquote:$rh_subject:}'\
```

Comment: I underline the colon after the $rh_subject !!!